# Can I use my existing SSL certificates on a new server with Plesk?

Tags: ssl, vps, ssl-certificate

We are migrating to a Virtual Private Server running on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS and with a Plesk configuration panel.

We have some valid SSL certificates on the old server, which I would like to use on the new configuration. I have the CSR, private key, certificate and CA-certificate.

I cannot find a way to change the CSR and private key in the Plesk configuration panel.

Anyone know, if this is possible and how?

Comment: **Questions involving web hosting control panels** are off-topic at [sf] because they [customize their systems beyond the ability to be supported in normal ways](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055), and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)

Answer (score 2):

On my Plesk 9.3 server, when I attempt to add a certificate, it prompts me for the Private Key, Certificate, and (optionally) the CA Certificate.  If you have those three components, you should be good to go.  You don't need the CSR if you already have a signed cert.

Note that you have to skip the first option on the page -- which allows you to Request, Buy, or Self-Sign a certificate.  Further down the page, there are options to either upload or paste in the three blocks for existing certificates.

I checked my Plesk 8.4 server, and the UI is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure with Plesk, but in CPanel it is not possible to use the old data. I think the question you should ask is how do you change the CSR and pk data in Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

Every CSR is different, you will have to make a new one.
Go to the website of the company issuing the SSL certificate and look for the redeem option.

This will let you enter a new CSR and make it valid on a new server. At least this is what I did.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what version of Plesk you are using , but this should help you out. [Link Here!!](http://download1.swsoft.com/Plesk/Plesk7/Doc/html/plesk-7-admins-manual/ch02s12.html)